# numpy column arrays and strange results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a function where its arguments are arrays with different shapes. I am having some troubles to understand column arrays and to make my function work for all shapes of arrays, here are the problems I found:

**Transposing:**
If the argument array `A` is not a vector then I can transpose it nicely using `A.T` however if `A` is a row vector this will NOT turn `A` into a column vector. If `A` is a column vector this will (strangely) turn it into a row vector. Is there a way to transpose an array independently of its shape?

**Dot Product**
The dot Product of a column vector with a scalar is a column vector (yeahh!). The dot Product of a column vector with a 1 element numpy array is a row vector (nayyy).

```
A = array((1,2)).reshape(2,1) #this is how I make a column vector (is there a better looking way?)
print dot(A,3) #column vector
b = dot(array((2,4)),a) #array with shape (1,)
print dot(A,b) #row vector..(bah)
```

**Inversion**

```
linalg.inv(array(2)) #gives an error, shouldn't it return 1/2 ?
```

Thanks for all the help!
P.S. Sorry for being noob I am used to Matlab this way of writing things is very confusing for me ..
P.S.2 I don't want to use matrices because arrays are more general

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're used to Matlab, Numpy's way of dealing with "column" and "row" vectors is a little strange. The thing to realize is that a 1-d array is *neither* a column nor a row vector. To be a column or row vector, an array has to be a *2-d array with one dimension set to one*. You can tell the difference between a 1-d array and a 2-d array with one row by looking at how many braces there are:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(15)
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> b = a.reshape(1, -1)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Now you can see that when you transpose these two, `a` stays the same, but `b` becomes a column vector:

```
>>> a.T
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> b.T
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10],
       [11],
       [12],
       [13],
       [14]])
```

Again, this may seem a little strange -- but as you say, "arrays are more general." To achieve that generality, Numpy distinguishes strictly between arrays of different dimensions; a 1-d array simply can't be a "column" or "row" vector in any meaningful sense. The second dimension isn't defined at all!

The answers to your other questions follow from this observation. Your code example code above generates an error for me, so I'll do something slightly different... which also generates an error, but a more informative one:

```
>>> A
array([[1],
       [2]])
>>> B
array([2, 4])
>>> numpy.dot(A, B)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Numpy complains that the objects are not aligned. That's because B is a 1-d array! Let's make it a true row vector:

```
>>> B = B.reshape(1, -1)
>>> B
array([[2, 4]])
>>> numpy.dot(A, B)
array([[2, 4],
       [4, 8]])
>>> numpy.dot(B, A)
array([[10]])
```

Now everything makes sense. Dot simply performs matrix multiplication here; in one order the operation produces a 2x2 array; in the other, it produces a 1x1 array. Note the number of braces! Both of these are *2-d* arrays. In turn, `10`, `[10]`, and `[[10]]` would all be different results.

Similarly, consider these three values:

```
>>> numpy.array(2)
array(2)
>>> numpy.array((2,))
array([2])
>>> numpy.array((2,)).reshape(1,-1)
array([[2]])
```

If you pass these to `numpy.linalg.inv`, you'll get errors for all but the last -- you can't take the matrix inverse of something that isn't a matrix! If you pass the last, the result is also a matrix:

```
>>> numpy.linalg.inv(numpy.array((2,)).reshape(1,-1))
array([[ 0.5]])
```

Comment: it all made perfect sense now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

### Transposing

It is important to distinguish between 1D arrays and 2D arrays. The row vector you are referring to is 1D, while the column vector is 2D. To demonstrate the difference, have a look at the following example.

First we demonstrate the default behavior of transposing a 2D array (even the column vector is a simple 2D array):

```
import numpy as np

print np.ones((3, 4)).T.shape
print np.ones((3, 1)).T.shape
```

The output is - as expected:

```
(4, 3)
(1, 3)
```

A 1D vector, however, does not change its size:

```
print np.ones((3,)).T.shape
```

Output:

```
(3,)
```

To quickly convert it into a 2D array, use `[:,None]`:

```
print np.ones((3,))[:,None].T.shape
```

Output:

```
(1, 3)
```

### Dot product

To obtain the desired result, you should better work with 2D arrays:

```
A = np.ones((2, 1)     # column vector
b = np.ones((1, 1))    # scalar
print np.dot(A, b)     # column vector (as expected)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

Yeah! :)

### Inversion

Again, you need to make sure to work with 2D arrays. This can be done using the `ndmin` argument:

```
print np.linalg.inv(np.array(2,ndmin=2))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.5]]
```